# Opensea JS after upgradingto 2.0 " You declined to authorize your offer" and " TypeError: Cannot read property 'EIP712Domain' of undefined"

Tags: truffle, opensea

I am asking here since OS support is not existent. I upgraded my version of the Opensea SDK to 2.0 and now I get these errors when trying to use the function "createBuyOrder". Did anyone on here experience this and solved it?

Comment: I am also having same error. any solution?

Comment: they published a beta of the 2.0 SDK, use that, It solves all errors for me and they gonna merge it after further testing

Comment: yeah, I am waiting for the merge. I solved it temporarily. I am sticking with it rnow

Comment: @BitQueen I'm running into this myself. How you describe how you solved it?

Comment: upgraded to their 2.0.1 beta and after that it got merged and worked again. I think same errors appear on the new version 3.0 rn on some peoples apps.